# Custom sp_who without granting view server state

Tags: sql-server

I need a stored procedure that I can give to a group of users that will allow them to see all running processes (like `sp_who`), but I don't want these users to have `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions as this will expose too much metadata.

I also need to allow the users to kill processes.

This is for a dev server dedicated to this group, and my goal is to allow this functionality without exposing more info than necessary.

Anyone have any ideas?

So far I've tried creating a stored procedure that calls `sp_who` as me (DBA), but the results only show the callers current process.

TYIA!!!

Comment: Well, [read the MSDN documentation on `sp_who`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) : *Permissions - Requires VIEW SERVER STATE permission on the server to see all executing sessions on the instance of SQL Server. **Otherwise, the user sees only the current session.*** So if your users don't have that permission, they won't ever see other sessions - period.

Comment: Why do you trust someone to see all running processes and kill processes, but you don't trust them with `sp_who`?

Comment: There is a former rogue DBA with zero accountability is in the group. The group does large ETLs in what's considered a data warehouse environment, so while developing they wasnt the ability to view and kill their processes on the dev server. If I expose more info about the server than necessary, this person will no doubt use it to my detriment. Imagine you have a former DBA that would love to expose anything he can find on your server to make you look bad - that's what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Love your icon btw; I'm scottish decent as well - Angus clan.

Comment: @user2174704 That doesn't sound like a terrible thing. Why do you feel that you don't need oversight especially if you know he'll find things that could be done better?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a stored procedure with an EXECUTE AS LOGIN SomeLogin with the Permission "View Server State" and grant the users access to that one for such needs.
Same for the kill command which you should wrap into such code + do some security checking first

Comment: Thanks @Andreas.Wolter